# Adding ASCII characters to HTML links in Drupal

Tags: theming

I've written the decimal HTML entry of the "[Logical or](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2228/index.htm)" ASCII note in a menu-link and yet I don't see the character. What I do see is the decimal HTML entry... Why is that? Is this problem solvable without any modules? Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Menu HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_html) module for that.

It uses a bunch of alter hooks, which means you could theoretically reproduce the same functionality in a theme if you really want to. So yes, it's possible to solve without using a module per se.

Modules are the proper way to add such functionality, though, hacking this into a theme is bad application design in my opinion. Drupal is, intentionally, a modular system; don't be scared of installing modules to add functionality, *that's what you're supposed to do* :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer --- Indeed, Drupal is modular but I'm sure we would agree that it's best to avoid installing modules if (!) there is an swift & easy non-modular solution, which is not the case here, So I guess a module-lover as myself will go and install Menu HTML. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep that's a good way to look at it